# Using Dir(FileName) to determine if file exists or not

Tags: excel, vba

I try to use Dir(FileName) to determine if the file exists or not. However, even I extracted the correct file name using the following code, Dir(FileName) returns empty regardless the file actually exists in the drive or not. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
 Sub SetUpTable()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, fName As String, SNumber As String, fPath As String, wbName As String

    wbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    SNumber = Left(wbName, InStr(wbName, "_") - 1)

    fPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws    
            
            fName = fPath & "\" & SNumber & " Tbl " & .Name
            
            If Dir(fName) <> vbNullString Then
                FileExistsWarning.Show    
            Else:
                Call ConvertToPDF    
            End If
                
     End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the file extension.

Comment: That's it I was missing! Thank you so much for your help!